# Ccan't get item from database with Axios and NestJS

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, axios, nestjs

I can't get item from Firebase Realtime Database with Axios and NestJS.

My code is:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}
  async getHello(): Promise<Observable<AxiosResponse<any>>> {
    const data = await this.httpService.get(
      '[my firebase url.]',
    ).pipe();
    return data;
  }
}
```

I get this error:

```
[Nest] 5104  - 01.11.2021 20:28:19   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
    |     property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'TLSSocket'
    --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
    |     property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'TLSSocket'
    --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (C:\Users\Faruk\Desktop\projects\fbase\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1123:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\Faruk\Desktop\projects\fbase\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:260:14)
    at ExpressAdapter.reply (C:\Users\Faruk\Desktop\projects\fbase\node_modules\@nestjs\platform-express\adapters\express-adapter.js:32:57)       
    at RouterResponseController.apply (C:\Users\Faruk\Desktop\projects\fbase\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-response-controller.js:14:36)
    at C:\Users\Faruk\Desktop\projects\fbase\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:175:48
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Faruk\Desktop\projects\fbase\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:47:13
    at C:\Users\Faruk\Desktop\projects\fbase\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:9:17
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you aren't mapping the response  at all. Axios responses are, by definition, circular, so you need to return only the part of the response you need. Most of the time, this is simply just `return this.httpService.get(url).pipe(map((resp) => resp.data))`